# Mac OS X - Force screen resolution

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, resolution

I'm trying to use the lastest version of a certain development tool and it's sort of difficult to use on a 1200x800 display. Using VMWare Fusion, I can set the screen resolution inside a VM to 1900x1200 on my 13" MBP and it's still usable. Does anyone know of a way to force Mac OS X to scale it's resolution? I tried ScreenResX and it said the scaled resolution was "invalid" or something like that.

I know that there are only a certain number of pixels on the screen. I'm only asking how to scale, not set a legit resolution. My current hack solution is to run Snow Leopard Server in a VM with resolution scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS X resolution independence isn't advanced enough. Even the *Quartz Debug* application included in the developer tools doesn't support scaling factors below 1.0.

The proper way to do this seems to be getting a bigger or higher-DPI screen.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't put a better DPI screen in my laptop without voiding the warranty hardcore, but your answer is accurate nonetheless.

Comment: while you can't put a bigger screen in your laptop, your laptop should have a monitor output which would allow you to plug in a higher resolution display